# Python, how do we concatenate two lists with a specific format then sum like elements?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists simplified as such, with the elements being single digits, please imagine every element in alist is a phone number and every element in blist represents the number of seconds of their call. I'm unsure if that makes a difference but I wish to be as specific as possible:

```
alist = [1,4,1,2,1]
blist = [6,7,8,9,5]
```

and I would like to sum the elements in blist which have the same int in alist, also it must be in numerical order according to alist. The output should look like this:

```
clist = [19,9,7]
```

I have tried using:

```
clist = [a + b for a, b in zip(alist, blist)]
```

to combine the lists then possibly summing it after but it seems to become more difficult. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Do you expect the sorting order to be 1,4,2 which is the order they appeared in alist or numerically 1,2,4?

Comment: @SirParselot - I think it's 1,2,4, going by the mention of "numerical order" and the resulting `[19, 9, 7]` (and ignoring the mention of "according to alist").

Comment: @SirParselot Late reply, but Tiger was correct it should be 1,2,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea using a dictionary to map the elements from `alist` to the sum of the corresponding elements of `blist`.

```
>>> alist = [1,4,1,2,1]
>>> blist = [6,7,8,9,5]
>>> d = {}
>>> for a,b in zip(alist, blist):
...     d[a] = d.get(a, 0) + b
... 
>>> [d[x] for x in sorted(d)]
[19, 9, 7]
```

Comment: I wonder if `[d[x] for x in sorted(d)]` would be faster/clearer?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think your idea reads better, I'll edit it in.

Comment: This was exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you timegeb!

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

alist = [1,4,1,2,1]
blist = [6,7,8,9,5]

# insert keys in sorted order
d = OrderedDict()
for key in sorted(set(alist)):
    d[key] = 0

# sum items
for a,b in zip(alist, blist):
    d[a] += b

# final result
clist = list(d.values())  # produces [19, 9, 7]
```

Comment: This appears useful, however is there a way to do this without importing from anything?

Comment: @LeBlanc Use timgeb's answer if you don't want to import anything

Answer (score 1):

Try [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)- where you can get times by number by indexing as like regular dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

alist = [1,4,1,2,1]
blist = [6,7,8,9,5]
for key, value in zip (alist,blist):
  d[key]+=value
print [i[1] for i in sorted(d.items())]
```

Output-

```
[19, 9, 7]
```

Comment: this does not guarantee the order

Comment: @timgeb What is the order here and how is being breached - please clarify- please.

Comment: It needs to be sorted based on the key. "also it must be in numerical order according to alist." straight from the question. Your answer is right but it isn't gauranteed

Comment: `sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[0])` has the same result as `sorted(d.items())`, because dictionary keys are unique and therefore will never have a collision that requires referring to the values.

Comment: THank you for your input :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Awesome** Counter class!

```
from collections import Counter

alist = [1,4,1,2,1]
blist = [6,7,8,9,5]
c = Counter()
for a,b in zip(alist, blist):
    c[a] += b
clist =  [v for k, v in sorted(c.items())]
print clist
```

I think this is best *tool* for the job

Comment: This appears useful, however is there a way to do this without importing from anything?

Comment: Not if you want "Counter". Why not to import?